# chrome.runtime.sendMessage raises "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'sendMessage' of undefined "

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a google chrome extension and trying to send information from a piece of code that is injected into a web page to my content script.

According to http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage, I should use something like :

```
// The ID of the extension we want to talk to.
var editorExtensionId = "abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoabc";

// Make a simple request:
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, {openUrlInEditor: url},
  function(response) {
    if (!response.success)
      handleError(url);
  });
```

The problem is, when I do :

```
var script_code = "var msg = {message : 'plop'};\n";
script_code += "chrome.runtime.sendMessage('" + chrome.i18n.getMessage("@@extension_id") + "', msg, function(response) {\n";
script_code += "    console.log('response received');\n";
script_code += "});\n";
```

An then inject this to the webpage, when it is executed, I get :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'sendMessage' of undefined

Can anyone help me through this ?

Thanks

Comment: Content scripts execute separately from javascript in a webpage, when you inject a script into a page it cannot talk directly to your content script. There are usually work arounds so post more details as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes @1337holiday , I know, that is why I am trying to use this messaging API to send  my data from the web page (through this injected script), to the event/background page, and then resend it from there to my content script, like it is described in the documentation. If there is a simpler way that is also safe, why not :-)

Answer (score 9):

javaScript code in Chrome extensions can be divided in the following groups:

- **Extension code - Full access to all permitted [chrome.*](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/api_index.html) APIs.**
  This includes all extension pages(background page, popup page ,option page, and so on)
- **[Content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts/) (via the manifest file or [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-executeScript)) - [Partial](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts/) access to some of the chrome APIs**
  Full access to the page's DOM.
- **Injected scripts (via [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/938089?building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) in a Content script) - Full access to all properties in the page. No access to any of the chrome.* APIs.**
  Execute on the actual page, can't access any of the [chrome.*](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/api_index.html) APIs.**.

In your case, code is execute on the actual page, can't call chrome.runtime.* APIs.
Maybe, you can try [window.postMessage()](http://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/#dom-window-postmessage).

Comment: in this doc https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage , it seems `chrome.runtime` can be accessed. but I got an error `Cannot read property 'sendMessage' of undefined`. why?

Answer (score 3):

Please check your manifest file and if you are using localhost ensure that matches are correct

**Incorrect:**

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["https://localhost:PORT_NUMBER/\*"]
}
```

**Correct:**

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["\*://localhost/\*"]
}
```

if its not localhost, please ensure that matches contains mask of at least 2 levels of domains [as described in documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/externally_connectable/)

> matches (array of string) - optional
>
> The URL patterns for web pages that are allowed to connect. This does not affect content scripts. If left empty or unspecified, no web pages can connect.
>
> Patterns cannot include wildcard domains nor subdomains of (effective) top level >domains; *://google.com/* and http://*.chromium.org/* are valid, while <all_urls>, >http://*/*, *://*.com/*, and even http://*.appspot.com/* are not.

Comment: yep, thakns. You helped me

Answer (score -4):

Well, in fact, I included the wrong version of the manifest.json file.

My bad, this is where you specify that you want to expose the messaging API to certain sites.

Problem solved.

Comment: Why won't you share your answer with the rest of us?, and no, 'problem solved' is not an answer

Comment: Could you please provide us the answer. I am too experiencing the same problem.